# if condition on turbo C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I'm having a problem regarding with if statement in C++ this statement is in do-while loop.

```
gotoxy(27,22);cout<<"Do you want to continue [Y]?";
    sub=getche();
    if(sub!='y' || sub!='Y')
    {

        gotoxy(27,24);cout<<"INVALID ANSWER!!";
        gotoxy(27,26);cout<<"Closing Program....";
        delay(3000);
        exit(1);
    }else
    {
        sub=ans;
    }
}while(tolower(ans)=='y');
```

whenever I input y on the variable sub the code on if statement is still executing.. please someone tells me where is the error.. Thanks!

Comment: Don't mix iostreams and stdio.  If you're using cout for output you should be using cin for input.  If you want to use getche for input use printf for output.

Comment: i didn't include stdio.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean expression of `(sub!='y' || sub!='Y')` will always evaluate to true

This line:

```
if(sub!='y' || sub!='Y')
```

Needs to be this:

```
if ( (sub != 'y') && (sub != 'Y') )
```

Comment: Note, while the extra parenthesis may clarify code, here they are not needed, and I think usually would not be used in a simple condition like this.

Comment: @hyde - The coding guidelines I have for my own team is to prefer extra parentheses around individual boolean expressions. It makes it clear what is being evaluated and avoids ambiguity about discerning operator precedence order. And I like to be consistent with regards to how I apply that style (i.e. always).  I know some will disagree...

Comment: I changed it to && but it just exit the program after I input y. and earlier i also tried to change it to if(tolower(sub)!='y') it still executing if statement code.. :(

Comment: @user2959418 - It likely is exiting because it continues to loop and reads a `\n` character.  Change your code to ignore `\n` (linebreak) chars.

Comment: I'm still newbie, how can I do it and so it will proceed to else statement?

Comment: @user2959418 - if the answer and comments resolved your issue, don't forget to "accept" (check) it.

Comment: @selbie I don't really disagree with that, just pointed it out because adding those parentheses here is an unexplained change to code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `if(sub!='y' || sub!='Y')` will be true ,no matter what you enter because either`sub!='y'` or `sub!='Y'` will evaluate to true. Hence Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: i tried to change it to && but it wont go through my else statement it exit the program instead. :(

Comment: Try to add a cout statement in else part and check whether any output is displayed or not